# Change order of html element depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

How do you change the order of html elements based on the size of the screen?

For example, on large screen like desktops, the order would be like this:

> element1 element2 element3

However, when seeing this on phone, it wouldn't fit the width of the screen. So, I would like it to look like this:

> element2
>   element1
>   element3

Since Div2 is the main div, I would like it to be on the middle on large screens and on top on smartphone screens.

I am using [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) as the framework for the website.

Here's an example code:

```
<div id="container" class="row medium-up-3">
   <div id="element1" class="column column-block">

   </div>
   <div id="element2" class="column column-block">

   </div>
   <div id="element3" class="column column-block">

   </div>     
</div>
```

I have spent a lot of time learning html and css so that's all I really know to make a website. I have been planning to learn javascript so it would be fine if the solution requires it.

Comment: can you use bootstrap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the CSS way, using flexbox (take a look at [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to help you get started with flexbox):

`flex-direction` is either `row` or `column` (depending on how you want your elements to flow)

Change their order with `order` (using `order: 1` on #element2 will put it at the end)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#element2 {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="row medium-up-3">
  <div id="element1" class="column column-block">
    #1
  </div>
  <div id="element2" class="column column-block">
    #2
  </div>
  <div id="element3" class="column column-block">
    #3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I tried this, it does make element2 the first element when it is vertical. However, now it is always vertical, even when the screen is wider.

Comment: add it in a [media query](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), `@media screen and (max-
width: 640px) { }`

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it:

In CSS you can use a media query to display or hide content:

```
@media (max-width:632px){
    #computer{
        display: none;
    }
    #phone{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

You can then have 2 x html sections for both computers / smartphones for example (If you'd like to have big differences in structure etc. between devices)

Good read on media queries - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html

Answer (score -1):

You just simply use class  medium-up-12 instead of class on container ID.
Goo Luck.

```html
<div id="container" class="row medium-up-12">
  <div id="element1" class="column column-block">
    #1
  </div>
  <div id="element2" class="column column-block">
    #2
  </div>
  <div id="element3" class="column column-block">
    #3
  </div>
</div>
```